# Show that $ker(\phi)=H$

Tags: group-theory, group-rings

Ler $R$ be a ring and $G$ be a group, $RG$ be the group ring and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. So if |$H$| is invertible in $R$, then setting $e_H=\frac {1} {|H|} \widehat {H}$ where $\widehat{H}=\sum_{h \in H} h$, I have to show that $\phi : G \to Ge_H$ defined by $g \to ge_H$ is a group epimorphism and $ker(\phi)=H$.

Now my problem is in showing $ker(\phi)=H$. As if I let $h \in H$ then $h$ goes to $he_H=\frac {h} {|H|} \widehat {H}$ but $h. \widehat {H}= \widehat{H}$ so $he_H=e_H$. Why is it identity?

Answer (score 1):

If $g\notin H$ then $H\cap gH=\varnothing$. You can check that the coefficient of elements of $H$ in $ge_H$ is zero, but the coefficient of elements of $H$ in $e_H$ is not zero, so they are not equal.

More precisely, remember the [formal definition of group ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring#Definition): it is the set of all functions $f:G\to R$ with finite support. $ge_H$ sends the elements of $H$ to zero, but $e_H$ sends the elements of $H$ to nonzero element of $R$.

Comment: But when $h \in  H$ then $hH=H$ and then $he_H=e_H$. I am sorry but not clear yet why $h \in H$ belongs to $ ker (\phi)$

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth My proof says that $he_H$ and $ee_H$ are not equal (where $e$ is the identity of $G$). By definition of kernel, it implies $g\not\in \operatorname{ker}\phi$.

Comment: You already prove that $he_H=e_H$ when $h\in H$ so if $h\in H$ then $h\in \operatorname{ker} H$. Combine with my result, we get $h\in H$ iff $h\in\operatorname{ker}\phi$.